# Immutable Data Structure - Application maintenance

Tags: clojure, reactjs, immutability

I have been reading about Immutable data structures and understood that change detection has been made easy . And quite often, I hear that it makes the application maintenance simpler and provides an easy to understand programming model. 
I need help to understand the way it simplifies the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Clojure community has embraced immutability and it is an eye opener. The best I can do is send you to the source: [Rich Hickey's essay on State](http://clojure.org/state?responseToken=6111fda3016bdf7fcffb7bc30e97457d) and his talk [The Value of Values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM). Rich explains how separating the concept of a variable into three distinct concepts: identity, state, and value helps you model your system and reason about it.

It boils down to this: in your programming model, you should only allow things to change if they change in the system you are trying to model. Otherwise you are adding moving parts (mutable variables and objects) to a model that doesn't need them. This makes it harder to understand the model (specially as time evolves) but has little or no benefit.

Even though reading helps, the only way to grok this is to program in a language that takes immutability as a default until you realize how most of the systems you model actually have only a handful of things that change instead of pages and pages of mutable variables.

Answer (score 1):

Immutability is certainly more embraced in functional languages than in imperative ones, even if you can have a Java programming style that limits mutability (see [this for immutability in Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ft4/)). That said, I will just comment on [functional/immutability] and [object/mutability].

I'm Clojure fan and find functional programming really powerful, but...

May be I spent too much time with `C++` & `Java` and not enough with `Lisp` & `Clojure`, but I reckon that the *simpler maintenance* argument has yet to be proven by facts. I'm not sure there are reliable surveys on the actual cost of maintenance in big production systems with data on the technology used and associated costs.

Certainly, in terms of LOC, language like `Clojure` are really more focused and concise than `Java`. Hence you can say that less code leads to less maintenance, but I think functional style gives really more compact code that needs a very focused attention to fully understand what a function is doing comparing to imperative style which is more verbose but kind of straightforward. One big advantage of functional programming associated with immutability, is the ability to isolate a function and experiment with it without the need to drag a heavy context of satellite objects or build a bunch of mocks, which is very often the case with OO languages. Putting aside the experimentation, a pure function won't modify its arguments, which **ease the fear** to break unintentionally some piece of code outside the scope of the function.

But, putting aside the merits of functional/immutability over oop/mutability, in terms of maintenance, my experience leads me to think that it's not the technology which is the main issue, but the design, code quality and evolution of this code over time even when the initial one was of good quality. By "good", I mean that the code is respectful of style conventions (like basic naming), managed complexity, and has a sensible test harness, in a continuous (or at least automated) build environment.

Then, the question becomes: is there a paradigm (functional/immutability, object-oriented/mutability) that enforced a better design and better code. My feeling is that functional languages are the land of computer science passionates, OTOH OOP is more mainstream. Isn't it because OOP is *easier* to apprehend or is ot just a matter of education? but then, in order to maintain a system in the long run, should one go for a "clever" functional environment with few people able to tackle it, or some mainstream OO technology - with its unsafeness or permissiveness - but lots of people having some knowledge in it?

Certainly the solution is to choose the right technologies (plural) with the right, motivated people...